# What's happening with IEEE 1363?

Tags: public-key, standards, p1363

IEEE 1363 (or more precisely, IEEE 1363-2000) - the IEEE Standard Specifications for Public-Key Cryptography - has been inactive for so long, that it is now [with status Inactive-Reserved by IEEE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232701/ieee-1363-is-inactive-reserved-having-been-withdrawn-on-2019-11-07-what-does), and even considered withdrawn since Nov 2019.

Yet, it appears like a relatively well written standards document by a respected standards organization, on a topic that people in this crypto stackexchange care about. Can you tell me your opinions on this standard? Do people not care about IEEE 1363? I am aware that there are alternatives. Is any of the alternative standards more popular these days, leaving others like 1363 to fall by the wayside? Are there some trends in public key cryptography that I may be unaware of, that have led to IEEE 1363 falling by the wayside? Or do people just go with whatever comes from NIST, so don't see the need for alternative standards from IEEE?

Sorry, I'm just speculating. But that doesn't satisfy my curiosity. Please do help enlighten me?

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 , but that's actually the same post I referenced here, and it didn't really say what happened. I was wondering if there might be more cryptography related reasons, e.g., 1363a specifies ECIES using AES-CBC whereas these days vulnerabilities have been discovered with AES-CBC and the community has moved on to alternatives like AES-GCM. But why couldn't 1363a have been updated with the times?

Comment: "Tricking volunteers into wasting their time is evil." -> are you saying that the cryptography community in general feels this way about the IEEE 1363 standardization efforts? That it is a waste of time, that people have to be tricked into volunteering?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice where your link went. My mistake. Deleted.